# Get all array elements in one array mongodb + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's assume I've collection which has the following structure;

```
{
  id:1,
  name: 'name1', 
  students: ['1', '2' , '3']
}
{
  id:2,
  name: 'name2', 
  students: ['11', '22' , '33']
}
...
```

I want to get all students element in one array.

I can do as:

```
db.collection.find({}, {students: 1, _id:0})
```

This returns me an array as;

```
result = [
   {students: ['1', '2', '3']},
   {students: ['11', '22','33']},   
]
```

However I want to get `result = ['1', '2', '3', '11', '22','33'];`

What is the most efficient way to get result just like this?

Comment: `var merged = result.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.students.concat(b.students);
});`

Comment: @RayonDabre the above comment very well qualifies to be an answer.

Comment: @Reddy, My guess is OP is looking for some conventional `mongo way` to get expected result..

Comment: oh!! may be. But then he still has the javasccript tag on.. So you can go ahead with the answer. i dont see any prob

Comment: Try this `db.collection.aggregate([
        {$group: {
            $push: {$each: '$students'}
        }}
    ]);` (I didn't test it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go JavaScript way, Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

Try this:

```js
var result = [{
  students: ['1', '2', '3']
}, {
  students: ['11', '22', '33']
}, ];
var merged = result.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.students.concat(b.students);
});
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggragation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$students'
},{
    $group: {
        _id: '1',
        students: {
            $push: '$students'
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with aggregation framework.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$project:{_id:0, students:1}},
   {$group:{_id:null, result:{$push:"$$ROOT"}}},
   {$project:{_id:0, result:1}}
])
```

This will emit:

```
{ 
    "result" : [
        {
            "students" : [
                "1", 
                "2", 
                "3"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "students" : [
                "11", 
                "22", 
                "33"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```